# Of the translations of the gambler

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, translation

What follows is a few sentences from two existing translation of The Gambler by FYODOR DOSTOEVSKY.
At first,I must say ,I don't want by any means to take PEVER and VOLOKHONSKY part. In my view ,however,the first translation is unintelligible in parts.perhaps,of course ,for me.

> The first translation:
>   *At length I returned from two weeks leave of absence to find that my patrons had arrived three days ago in Roulettenberg*.

I can't understand the sentence after 'to find that'. I feel the translator should have written the sentence in this way:

> My interpretation: *At length I returned from two weeks leave of
>   absence to find that my patrons ( who ) had arrived three days ago in
>   Roulettenberg*.

Namely,we must add WHO to the sentence
And,according to the story ,patrons is also disproportionate.

Now,please,pay attention to the second translation .

> The second translation: *I've finally come back from my two-week absence.our people have already been in Roulettenburg for three days*.

Is my criticism just?

Comment: The first one means:  *Eventually I returned from two weeks leave of absence, and discovered that my patrons had arrived in Roulettenberg three days earlier.* This is essentially what the second one means, too.

Comment: Thanks.but ,I wonder I think the first isn't correct grammatically. In general ,I understand both.thank you ,again

Comment: You're confusing two meanings of *find*. [See ODO.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/find) The relevant one here is *Discover or experience to be the case*. So the meaning is: *I learned that my patrons had arrived in Roulettenberg three days earlier.*

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a sentence like "He found that the meal was served with a freshly baked loaf of bread". Replace *meals* by *patrons*, *was served* by *had arrived* and *with...* by *three...*.

Comment: "At length I returned from two weeks leave of absence to find **that** my patrons had arrived three days ago in Roulettenberg."  He's not finding his patrons, he's finding out something about their arrival.

Comment: Further to the previous comments, the original sentence is fine, and adding the word *who* would render it ungrammatical. But you could say “[…] to find my patrons, who had arrived three days ago in Roulettenberg.”

Answer (score 1):

As regards grammar, there is nothing wrong in the first translation. We may add "WHO" but in that case we need to remove "that" as used in the sentence. I don't know Russian. Translations never do full justice to a literary piece. It seems to me that the first translation is, perhaps, literal or ad verbum while the latter holds the spirit or Intent. Way of speaking the same thing differs from language to language, and a literal translation often runs the danger of giving wrong signal to foreign ears.

Translations, be it literal or free, are not foolproof.